# How can I save a phpBB-3 site? Admin passed away and no way to SQL dump :( So far I have this, but not getting the content of posts

Tags: javascript, php, regex, perl, http

I'd like to preserve the site posts as it goes back years, but nobody has access to the database after the site admin passed away. :(
Is there a better way to do this?

This is what I have so far. It is saving topics and what not, but not the content. I'd like to download the posts under each category and import them into SQL using either vanilla, myBB, flarum  or phpBB (have not decided which). Output:

Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in substitution (s///) at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 56.

Use of uninitialized value $year in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Use of uninitialized value $month in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Use of uninitialized value $day in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Wide character in print at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 71.

Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in concatenation (.) or

string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 73.

Saved sitename-topic-00001-page-000----

General_discussion_Expecting_Rain.html ( total posts)

Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in numeric gt (>) at

./fetch-phpbb.pl line 75.

Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in substitution (s///) at

./fetch-phpbb.pl line 56.

Use of uninitialized value $year in concatenation (.) or string at

./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Use of uninitialized value $month in concatenation (.) or string at

./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Use of uninitialized value $day in concatenation (.) or string at

./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

Wide character in print at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 71.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

require LWP::UserAgent;
use POSIX qw/ceil/;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');
$ua->timeout(10);

my $sid = 'efba981e5f1d54639b2bb67d8adf2a11';

$ua->default_header('Host' => 'expectingrain.com');
$ua->default_header('Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
$ua->default_header('Accept-Language' => 'en-us,en;q=0.5');
$ua->default_header('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate');
$ua->default_header('DNT' => '1');
$ua->default_header('Connection' => 'keep-alive');
$ua->default_header('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0');
#$ua->default_header();

my $max_topic_id = 20000;
my $posts_per_topic_page = 30;
my $topics_per_forum_page = 50;

my $output_file_name_base = 'sitename-';

my $base_url = 'https://expectingrain.com/discussions/viewforum.php?f=6';

my %status = ();

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $max_topic_id; $i++) {
        my $posts_in_topic = 0;
        my $url = $base_url . '?sid=' .$sid . '&t='.$i;

        my $response = $ua->get($url );
        if ($response->is_success) {
                my $page_content = $response->decoded_content;
                # [ 621 posts ]
                if ($page_content =~ /topic does not exist/) {
                        print STDERR "$url: Topic $i does not exist\n";
                        $status{'invalid topic'}++;
                } elsif ($page_content =~ /not authorised/) {
                        print STDERR "$url: Not authorized\n";
                        $status{'unauthorized'}++;
                } elsif ($page_content =~ /requires you to be registered and logged in/) {
                        print STDERR "$url: Login prompt.\n";
                        $status{'login message'}++;
                } elsif ($page_content =~ /forum you selected does not exist/) {
                        print STDERR "$url: Forum does not exist\n";
                        $status{'forum dne'}++;
                } else {
                        $posts_in_topic = ($page_content =~ / ([\d,]+) post(s?) /)[0];
                        $posts_in_topic =~ s/,//;
                        $status{'valid post'}++;
#                        print "Topic #$i contains $posts_in_topic posts\n";

                        my $title = ($page_content =~ /<title>(.+)<\/title>/)[0];
                        $title =~ s/[^\w\s]+//g;
                        $title =~ s/\s+/_/g;

                        # <td class="postbottom" align="center">Sat Nov 01, 2008 9:00 pm</td>
                        my ($crap, $wd, $month, $day, $year) = ($page_content =~ />((\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d{4})) \d+:\d{2} ..<\/td/);
                        my $date_str = "$year-$month-$day";

                        my $output_filename = sprintf("$output_file_name_base"."topic-%05d-page-000-$date_str-$title.html",$i);

                        open(FILE, ">$output_filename") or die $!;
                        print FILE $page_content;
                        close(FILE);
                        print "Saved $output_filename ($posts_in_topic total posts)\n";

                        if ($posts_in_topic > $posts_per_topic_page) {
                                my $total_pages = ceil($posts_in_topic / $posts_per_topic_page);
                                for (my $j = 1; $j < $total_pages; $j++) {
                                        my $start = $j * $posts_per_topic_page;
                                        my $page_url = $url . '&start='.$start;
                                        my $page_filename = sprintf("$output_file_name_base".'topic-%05d-page-%03d.html',$i, $j);
                                        my $page_response = $ua->get($page_url, ':content_file' => $page_filename);
                                        if ($page_response->is_success) {
                                                print "Saved Content File $page_filename\n";
                                        } else {
                                                print STDERR "Error fetching $page_url: {$response->status_line}\n";
                                        }
                                }

                        }

                 #       print $page_content;
                }

        } else {
                print STDERR "Error fetching $url: {$response->status_line}\n";
                $status{'error:'.$response->status_line}++;
        }

}
```

Comment: There are methods for changing the for password on a MYSQL system. I'd start there. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Yes but its a remote system in Norway, I only speak English. There's no way I'm going to be able to call up and say Yeah, I wanna change this persons database password.

Comment: You would be surprised how many people speak decent English in Norway...

Comment: I'd like to preserve the forum posts before the site goes offline due to an earthly departure, but changing the password, I do not think that is going to be a viable option.

Comment: Maybe try to use dedicated software to do this. I used [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) for this kind of job and it works well.

Comment: *"Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in substitution (s///) at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 56"* I assume that line 56 is this line `$posts_in_topic =~ s/,//;` ? It means that the previous line could not extract the information (`$post_in_topic`) from `$page_content`. You could print out the value of `$page_content` as a debugging aid to see why it cannot extract the information

Answer (score 1):

So on the first request, your program gets this URL:

- https://expectingrain.com/discussions/viewforum.php?f=6?sid=efba981e5f1d54639b2bb67d8adf2a11&t=1

That returns a 200 response code and the content contains none of the strings that your code looks for so you end up in the `else` block in the `if ($page_content =~ /.../)` code. That starts with these lines:

```
$posts_in_topic = ($page_content =~ / ([\d,]+) post(s?) /)[0];
$posts_in_topic =~ s/,//;
```

That searches your page content for a string that consists of a number of digits and commas, followed by a space, the word "post" and an optional "s". It then removes the first comma from the found string. It's that second line (the one removing the comma, that is giving you the error saying:

> Use of uninitialized value $posts_in_topic in substitution (s///) at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 56.

But if you look at the page, you'll see that there is no string made up of a number (including commas) followed by "post" or "posts". There is, however, a string near the top of the page that says "27559 topics".

Your next errors are these:

> Use of uninitialized value $year in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.
> Use of uninitialized value $month in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.
> Use of uninitialized value $day in concatenation (.) or string at ./fetch-phpbb.pl line 66.

And, if you look at the code, you'll see a similar piece of code:

```
my ($crap, $wd, $month, $day, $year) = ($page_content =~ />((\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d{4})) \d+:\d{2} ..<\/td/);
my $date_str = "$year-$month-$day";
```

Again, we're trying to match data and store it in variables. We're looking for three alphanumerics (`\w{3}`), three more alphanumerics (`\w{3}` again), two digits (`\d{2}`) and four digits (`\d{4}`) and storing them in the variables `$wd` for weekday?), `$month`, `$day` and `$year`. All of which makes me think we're looking for dates that look like "Mon Dec 27, 2021". And, again, looking at the page there are no dates in that format on that page. All of the dates are like "Mon December 27th, 2021".

I'm not sure where you got this code from, but it looks to me like it's written for a different version of phpBB - one that formats the data on the page in a different way to that expected by the code.

You can probably fix these problems by changing the code.

```
$posts_in_topic = ($page_content =~ / ([\d,]+) post(s?) /)[0];
```

Should become:

```
$posts_in_topic = ($page_content =~ /([\d,]+) topic(s?)/)[0];
```

And

```
my ($crap, $wd, $month, $day, $year) = ($page_content =~ />((\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d{4})) \d+:\d{2} ..<\/td/);
```

Should become something like:

```
my ($wd, $month, $day, $year) = ($page_content =~ />(\w{3}) (\w{3,9}) (\d{2})\w\w, (\d{4}) \d+:\d{2} ..<\/td/);
```

(Actually, that last one doesn't work as the HTML on the page is different too - I don't have time to investigate further.)

So, all-in-all, this program isn't made for your site. You might be able to hack at this one or you might find one that's useable for your version of phpBB.

But I really think the best option is to get in touch with the web hosting company, explain the situation and see how they can help you. Honestly, in my experience most Norwegians speak better English than most Brits :-)